# When I insert in database through connectionless i found a error null exception

Tags: c#, dataset

Here I found error in newrow

```
 DataRow drnew = ds.Tables["SMaster"].NewRow();// here i found error 
 drnew[0] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
 drnew[1] = textBox2.Text;`enter code here`
 drnew[2] = textBox3.Text;
 drnew[3] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
 ds.Tables["SMaster"].Rows.Add(drnew);
 da.Update(ds, "Smaster");
 MessageBox.Show("Record added");
 dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Smaster"];
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Would be awesome if you tell us which error you found ;)

Comment: add `if(ds.Tables["SMaster"] !=null){...//your code}`

Comment: @sanjeev : either `ds` or  `ds.Tables["SMaster"]` is null, take a close look